# AutoMapper: Action on each element during collection processing?

Tags: collections, action, automapper

Is it possible to invoke a method on each object that is being copied from a source to a destination collection using AutoMapper?  The destination object has a method called
Decrypt() and I would like it to be called for each CustomerDTO element that is created.  The only thing that I can figure out is to perform the mapping conversion and then loop again to invoke the Decrypt() method.  I'd appreciate your help with this question.

Thanks,

Mike

```
IQueryable<CustomerDTO> dtos = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IQueryable<CustomerEntity>,     IQueryable<CustomerDTO>>((BaseRepository.List));

foreach (var item in dtos)
{
    item.Decrypt(Seed);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you are decrypting just a property or the whole object.  I wasn't sure based on your question.

If you are just decrypting properties, then I suggest that you look into AutoMapper's [Custom Value Resolvers](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers).  They allow you to take control when resolving a destination property.

If you need to decrypt the whole object, then I suggest you look into AutoMapper's [Custom Type Converters](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters).  That gives you complete control over the conversion, though it does sort of take the auto out of AutoMapper.

Comment: Hi Rich, Thank you very much for the suggestions and clear explanations!  Each of the objects in the list knows how to encrypt and decrypt itself, so I think that the Custom Type Converter will be the way to go.  I will test things tomorrow.  Thanks again for your help!